# using native pdf viewer of mobile device in Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: kendo-mobile, pdf-viewer

I do have a Kendo UI Mobile app which I created with the VS Icenium extension. My question is if it is possible to open remote pdf documents with the native pdf viewer which is installed on a mobile device.

Currently, I'm using this code in order to open a document:

```
if (device.platform === "Android")
  window.open(data.uri, '_blank');
}
else
  window.open(data.uri, '_system');
}
```

This opens the browser and downloads the file, which is retrieved from a wep.api .NET MVC webservice. On iOS it works quite well. But on Android it opens the browser and starts the file download in the background and the document is not opened in the browser. It is necessary to pull down the message center in order to open the file.

But like I said, it would be great if I could check if a pdf viewer is installed on iOS / Android and ask the user to open the document with it otherwise opening the file in the browser using the code from above.

Searching the internet the only option I was able to find was pdf.js (which I wasn't able to implement into my app).

I'm an absolute beginner with HTML5, jquery, Kendo UI Mobile etc. and it would be great if you guys could give me your help!

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
 Martin